# How do I reuse the same code between files with the option to pass in arguments in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've noticed I have a set of `UIViewController`'s for a product filtering system that use the exact same code. This code basically creates buttons for a `UIToolBar` and hides the `UIToolBar` of the controller that presented it. The only difference will be the title that says "refine by:.

On each page I'll have the type of page it is after "refine by" so for example: On the gender filtering page it will say "Refine by: then I'll append another string in bold that says "Gender" for the products type page I'll append a bold string that says "Product type" and so on.

**Here is the code that is repeated in each of the custom classes connected to these controllers:**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolBar;


@end

@implementation VAGRefineProductTypeViewController
{
    VAGRefineProductTypeViewController *_thisController;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        _thisController = self;
    }
    return self;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

UIToolbar *toolBar = [_thisController toolBar];

[[_thisController navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
[_thisController setTitle:@"R  E  F  I  N  E     B  Y:"];

// Setup buttons for tool bar
UIButton *clearButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 3, 110, 38)];
UIButton *doneButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 3, 110, 38)];

[clearButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[doneButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

[clearButton setTitle:@"Clear" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[doneButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[clearButton addTarget:_thisController action:@selector(clearButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[doneButton addTarget:_thisController action:@selector(doneButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// Add buttons to toolbar
[toolBar addSubview:clearButton];
[toolBar addSubview:doneButton];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Hide previous pages tool bar
    [[_thisController navigationController] setToolbarHidden:YES animated:NO];
}

- (IBAction)clearButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"CLEAR BUTTON TAPPED");
}

- (IBAction)doneButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"DONE BUTTON TAPPED");
}
```

This `UIToolBar` is added to each `UIViewController` in interface builder. The one that is hidden in viewWillAppear is the one added programmatically from `UIViewController` that presented the current `UIViewController`.

Question:

Rather than copying and pasting this code into each `UIViewController`'s class file how can I put it in a file and use that file within each `UIViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various options. Probably the simplest is to define a base UIViewController class that defines the shared properties and methods, and then make all the view controllers that use these properties subclasses of that class.

Another option would be to define a category of UIViewController that defines new methods. That doesn't let you add new properties or instance variables to your view controllers however (at least not without getting tricky.)

Comment: So I would define the base class. Then add all those methods and the toolbar property to this base class. Then just change the classes of each view controller to be a subclass of the base controller? How would I call the methods of the base class?

Comment: @LondonGuy, this is very basic OOP stuff. You might want to pick up a book on object-oriented programming and do some reading. Otherwise you're going to struggle needlessly.

Comment: I agree. Coming from ruby on rails this stuff should come to mind automatically. It's not that I don't know how to do it but I just seem to forget objective-c has the ability to do these things. I tend to miss some obvious work arounds. I guess practice makes perfect. Took me a while to get into the groove of programming since returning late last year. The more complex an app gets the more I need to do and the more I get to learn. So next time I need to reuse code I can take this route or use categories. There are even other ways I've found I could have done this but this was most suitable.